# Contar linhas com PHP e JS (Diferente)

Tags: php, javascript

Estou precisando de uma função que me ajude contar determinadas divs no meu php.
Vou explicar melhor, eu tenho um verificador de produtos, ele funciona da seguinte forma, eu insiro os codigos dos produtos no textarea, coloco pra buscar e ele faz uma verificação no banco de dados. Os produtos que ja tem, ele retorna como reprovado, os que nao tem ele retorna como aprovado.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function buscarProdutosRepro(str) {
            document.getElementById(\'listProdutosRepro\').innerHTML += \'<div>\' + str + \'</div>\';
        }

        function buscarProdutosApro(str) {
            document.getElementById(\'listProdutosApro\').innerHTML += \'<div>\' + str + \'</div>\';
        }

        function FormatoInvalido(str) {
            document.getElementById(\'FormatoInvalido\').innerHTML += \'<div>\' + str + \'</div>\';
        }
    </script>
```

Essa função, ela é aplicada aqui

```
<center>
    <p style="background: #54bd0e; padding: 6px 20px; width: 180px; font-size: 13px; border-radius: 15px; color: #F0F0F0;">Produtos Carregados ('.$conta.') </p>
</center>
<div class="panel panel-green">
    </span>
    <div class="alert alert-success"><small>✔ Produtos Aprovados</small></div>
    <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" style="font-size:24px"></i> Verificando...
    <div class="panel-body">
        <br/><div id="listProdutosApro"></div>
    </div>
</div>                              
<div class="panel panel-danger">
    <div class="panel-heading"><small>✘ Produtos Reprovados</small></div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <br/><div id="listProdutosRepro"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-orange">
    <div class="panel-heading">Invalidas</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <br/><div id="FormatoInvalido"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Ela vai printando na tela os resultados, div em baixo de div.

```
<br/><div id="listProdutosApro">
<br/><div id="listProdutosApro">
<br/><div id="listProdutosApro">
```

Resultado: http://image.prntscr.com/image/ebb07cbb7bf547d98406cad16ef39e2f.png

e eu quero contar essas divs, como se fossem linhas, pra  assim:

✔ Produtos Aprovados  (80) <- essa soma que eu preciso.

✘ Produtos Reprovados (15) <- essa soma que eu preciso.

Se alguem poder, me ajudar, desde ja obrigado.

Comment: é mais ou menos isso http://jsfiddle.net/t6Z5s/ só que essa função conta a  quebra de linha de um textarea

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que eu entendi, em JavaScript seria assim:

```js
$(function() {
  var quantidade1 = document.getElementById('reprovados').children.length;
  
  var quantidade2 = document.getElementById('aprovados').children.length;
  
  $('.resultado').text(
      quantidade1/2 + " foram reprovados e " +
      quantidade2/2 + " foram aprovados"
  );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="panel-body" id="reprovados">
  <br/><div id="listProdutosRepro"></div>
  <br/><div id="listProdutosRepro"></div>
  <br/><div id="listProdutosRepro"></div>
</div>

<div class="panel-body" id="aprovados">
   <br/><div id="listProdutosAprov"></div>
   <br/><div id="listProdutosAprov"></div>
   <br/><div id="listProdutosAprov"></div>
   <br/><div id="listProdutosAprov"></div>
   <br/><div id="listProdutosAprov"></div>
</div>

<div class="resultado">
</div>
```

Onde tenho uma lista de aprovados e reprovados, tenho de contar quantos de cada eu tenho, então pego o elemento com o `id` 'reprovados', que seria a lista de resultados, e conto quantos filhos aquele elemento tem, no caso eu divido por dois pois cada elemento possui uma `div` e um `br`. No fim coloco o texto na tela.

Comment: da uma olhada http://image.prntscr.com/image/350f0f519acb4836a402666bb2bab7c7.png - http://image.prntscr.com/image/ee4f3e5688324b3c831d9f3e3cb90d61.png

Comment: O primeiro código é javascript com Jquery e não PHP

Comment: eu coloquei ele assim http://prntscr.com/cwy4nt e me volta esse erro http://prntscr.com/cwy4s9

Comment: so pra anexar, meu arquivo é um php que da echo pra printar o html, tipos assim http://prntscr.com/cwyj47

Comment: Você está misturando PHP com Javascript/HTML, ele está tentando ler esse código com se fosse PHP. Provavelmente você não fechou a tag php com ?>

Comment: Fechei amigo, a pagina esta funcionando normalmente se eu tirar esse código que você enviou. o erro acontece na linha que eu colocar ele. Mas não me adianta muito tirar o código, a página voltar a funcionar e eu não ter resolvido o problema inicial :s

Comment: Edite a pergunta colocando todo o código junto com o código que coloquei pra mim dar uma olhada, sem print, o código mesmo da pagina toda.

Comment: Eu pensei em fazer isso antes, mas o dono da loja não deixou. Eu percebi que quando eu troco aspas simples do seu código pra aspas duplas, ele vai pulando o erro pra outra linha que tem aspas simples. Eu ja tive esse problema antes, lembro que pra resolver era so uma questão de interpretação mesmo. Mas ja tentei de tudo aqui.

Comment: Eu precisei excluir algumas coisas pra me autorizarem a postar. assim serve amigo? http://pastebin.com/psgWV61f

Comment: Eu precisei excluir algumas coisas pra me autorizarem a postar. assim serve amigo? pastebin.com/psgWV61f

Comment: Há várias quebras de string no código o recomendável é colocar o HTML da página fora das tag  `<?php ?>`, todo `echo` de mais e uma linha que não tenha uma variável PHP deveria ser escrita fora das tag do PHP, porque assim você evita essa confusão de colocar todo seu HTML como string.